# PHP/AJAX stored procedure issue

Tags: ajax, stored-procedures, pdo

I'm having an issue with a stored procedure launched via a select change event. My problem is that even though I'm able to get the selected item's value, while I pass it as an argument to the stored procedure and bind it, the procedure doesn't launched. I've tried to launch it statically and it works.
I have already tried to change the dataType and Mime Type and other stuffs but I'm stuck.
Here's the code:

```
$groupe = new Groupe();

if (isset($_POST['value'])){

    $param = $_POST['name'];

    $storedProcedure = 'Call listeTitresParGroupe(:groupes)';

    $query = $groupe->prepare($storedProcedure);
    $query->bindParam(':groupes', $param, PDO::PARAM_STR);


    $query->execute();

    echo $_POST['name'].' -> '.$param.'   '.$storedProcedure;
    echo '<table class="table table-hover col-lg-12">';

    while ($resultat = $query->fetch()){

        echo'<tr><td class="col-md-12">'.$resultat[0].'</td></tr>';

    }
    echo '</table>';
}
```

The AJAX code:

```
var selectedText = {value: $('#groupe option:selected').text(),  name:$('#groupe option:selected').text()};

    $.ajax({

        url: './storedProcedures.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'text',
        mimeType : 'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
        data: selectedText

    })
    .done(function(data){$('#titres').html(data);})
    .fail(function() {

        console.log("Erreur");
        alert('AJAX query has failed');

    })
    .always(function() {

        console.log("Terminé");

    });
```

If anyone has an idea why it doesn't work, I'd be very grateful

Comment: there are no stored procedures in ajax. choose one realm you are working with

Answer (score -1):

Just to try it in a different way, you might try removing the bind:

```
$query->bindParam(':groupes', $param, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

and try just putting your param in the execute function:

```
$query->execute(array(':groupes'=>$param));
```

It is one less line of code, and worth a try maybe just to see if that also fails.

Comment: MinnesotaSlim thanks for your answer, I've tried you solution but it still doesn't work, does anyone have any idea? It really seems to me that the problem is due to the fail binding of the parameter...